Tried a lot of fixes, but still getting blank Github Page when trying to deploy React Web App
I've been trying to hoist my React Web App onto a gh-page for a while, but it doesn't break and loads as blank. The link is here: https://00eemsy.github.io/my-cv-website/
I've tried numerous things as recommended on other Stack Overflow posts, but none of them have worked:

I changed package.json's "private": true to "private": false
I've triple-checked my homepage URL ("homepage": "https://00eemsy.github.io/my-cv-website")
I've implemented BrowserRouter into my index.js file

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    {/* <App/> */}

    <nav>
      <Link to='/'></Link>
    </nav>

    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<App />}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Everything looks fine on localhost, npm run build and gh-pages -d build don't break, but I still get a blank webpage on any other device or any other web browser that isn't Chrome (my most frequently used browser). Pretty sure there aren't faulty links, but it seems like it only shows up fine on Chrome but nowhere else.

This method worked for me: https://dev.to/rashidshamloo/deploying-vite-react-app-to-github-pages-35hf
Dont forget to set the publishing source to the gh-pages branch in Github Settings > Pages > Build and Deployment

Appreciate it, but I didn't set my React App up with Vite so the instructions don't work :(
Second part's already covered. Still nothing.

The only Vite-specific step is the base url and theres probably an equivalent in your setup

"deploy": gh-pages -d dist is also different (mine was "deploy: gh-pages -d build instead). either way, it didn't seem to work. ty though
